# how to modify requests to files inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension, I know I can monitor and modify web requests by adding listener to [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) event.
but how can I monitor and modify requests to files inside chrome, like:
I need to redirect this request:

```
chrome-extension://papeocdpfbliedsdsnppdccocpdfdfajo/sample.js
```

to this url

```
https://cdn.example.com/sample.js
```

Note: Because some websites like github.com refuse to request to any external resources, but it's possible to append a script with src to files inside chrome extension, I want to create a url alias or any other proxy-like approach to get the content from my server instead of a static file inside chrome extension.

Comment: Why aren't you storing the file within the extension?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it's getting generated dynamically in server. I want to use this as a proxy for situations that external requests are banned in some websites such as github and pinterest

Comment: Important clarification: you're targeting links inside your extension, correct? Not trying to hijack `chrome-extension:` URLs for other extensions?

Comment: @Xan I've added a note. Have a look please. No I'm not hijacking from an extension to other extension

Comment: `webRequest` API documentation mentions that you can intercept `chrome-extension:` schema for your own extension.